# Shouldn't a question end in a question mark?

Tags: discussion

This is not a question though I posed it as a question to avoid being accused of being hypocritical. What I'm really after is that I would respectfully ask that on BE, questions be posed as actual questions instead of cryptic click bait. For example "Judas' Kiss" or "Pharaoh's Army" are not questions and one would have to open the question to find out what the questioner wants to know.

Also, respectfully, I ask that when possible the question include the scripture passage that the question related to.

No response necessary or even desired. Thanks and have wonderful day.

Comment: Yes, pretty much every question on this site should be titled in a way that frames the basic question and should end in a properly applied question mark.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, questions should always end in a question mark. However, the bolded text over the body of questions is not a question, but a *title* indicating the topic of the question. It may therefore be approperiate at times for the heading or title of the question to end in other types of punctuation.

Therefore, there should be at least one question mark *in the body* of the question. When questions are scriptural should include the passage (though there may be times where a question is about a hermeneutic method, and not a passage itself in which case there is no need to include the passage).

As an aside, I want to note that I (for one) really appreciate your edits. You have turned into one of our more prolific question editors and I think it really does improve the quality of questions (so if you want to make sure these rules are in force as you come across them, I am happy to continue approving your edits in most cases; and thank you for your hard work).

Comment: Distinguishing titles from questions is fine, as long as it's clear that non-question titles should be quite rare. 95% of the time, maybe more, the title should be a question.